# Unstable wifi Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

Recently I had  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed due not liking  windows 8 and had trouble installing windows 7 
Btw complete newb on Ubuntu !
My problem is that the wifi connection is horrible I cannot connect at all!  But did manage to have a connection when it was first installed then after that just didn't connect anymore

I've tried:

1. Deleting the wifi profile and reconnect
2. Reset network manager

Don't know what else to do.

```
Network card
     description: Ethernet interface 
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller 
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0 
       logical name: eth0 
       version: 10
       serial: 28:d2:44:f7:a7:30
       size: 10Mbit/s 
       capacity: 1Gbit/s 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet     physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000 bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation 
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=Half firmware=Rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=No multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s 
       resources: irq:60
       ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0504000-c0504ddd memory:c0500000-c0503fff 
  *-network 
       description: Wireless interface 
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 
       vendor: Realtek semiconductor Co.,Ltd.
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0 
       logical name: wlan0 
       version: 00
       serial: 10:08:b1:71:65:59
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless 
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.13.0-45-generic    firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.66 latency=0 link=No multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn 
       resources: irq:19 
       ioport:3000(size:256) memory:c0400000-c0403fff
```

Answer (score 0):

add this option in kernel drivers settings

> $ sudo echo 'options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1' >>
>   /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf

Then restart the system this must fix wifi problem.

Comment: How would that work when the person does not even have that driver?

Comment: Yeah I was going to say I can't even find the kernel driver.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

used this code line +restarted laptop and now my wi-fi connection is stable  :)

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit? Your answer is showing up in the low-quality queue. Perhaps adding how to get into the terminal and citing a source would do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: If you give someone a fish, he will not be hungry for a day.  If you teach him to fish, he will not be hungry for the rest of his life.  Please explain what you're doing here and why...